# JupyterLab 3.6.3 / 4.0.8 / 4.0.9 Debugger Not Enabled, when I hover it says "Select a kernel that supports debugging to enable debugger"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to using Jupyter lab however debugger in all these versions 3.6.3 / 4.0.8 / 4.0.9 is showing the same message "Select a kernel that supports debugging to enable debugger";even that now ipykernel is supported. I am using anaconda navigation; I have uninstall and installed anaconda and jupyter lab several times and have updated conda as well.
[This is how my screen is displaying the message for Jupyter Lab 4.0.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuWX8.png)
Really Appreciate the help here.

Tried version 3.6.3, 4.08, 4.0.9 but all resulted in the same error. Also same for Jupyter notebook using 7.0.6

Comment: So, I created a new environment and then it worked. However when I did conda update conda it again shows disabled. Not sure why

Comment: One reason for it breaking could be if `conda update` modifies kernel spec. You can run `jupyter kernelspec list` and find the specification of the kernel you are using; there will be a JSON file with "metadata" entry. Does it have debugger field?

Comment: when I pass jupyter kernelspec list, get the following
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Available kernels:

Comment: Manually set the debug flag to true in the kernel.json file located in your anaconda installation folder anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3 worked for me. Indeed conda update looks like it is setting this to false.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after manually overwriting it.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Is this a known bug? Difficult to get a bunch of people to edit kernel.json file in a workshop setting.

Comment: @j-goedhart, please post your answer with the mentioned `jupyter kernel spec list` command. It solves the problem.